# Menu same size of parent SplitMenuButton javaFX

Tags: java, javafx, menu

Im working in JavaFX whit FXML and i want to make a top menu with resize properties and constrained growth for this i use SplitMenuButtons inside a GridePane it works well but i have problems when i add the menus it looks like this

[image: https://postimg.org/image/566jrsvpj/]

the menu pouts up very small

my idea was to put a listener in the widthProperty of the SplitMenuButton and then set menu.prefWidth but the menu does not have a setPrefWidth or prefWidth method

so i work around it and make this code that adds a label with padding but it looks ugly and i dont know how to get the correct size because of the text of the menu and also i dont know how to calculete the size of the text in the menu this is what i get

[image: https://s31.postimg.org/96o9nxch7/image.png]

it looks very ugly and it behaves randomly my code for this is as follow

```
 SplitMenuButton.widthProperty().addListener((e,n,v)->{
        Label lal = new Label(">");
        Insets inces = new Insets(0,0,0,n.intValue());
        lal.setPadding(inces);
        Menu.setGraphic(lal);
    });
```

i'm looking for a way to make the menu the same size and the menu items also of the same size the result i'm looking for is something like this

[image: https://s32.postimg.org/z6zel4tbp/image.png]

sorry for the bad pic is the only thing i got at hand

so how i make what im looking for?, change the type of node for the 4 top menus?, CSS (but i think a change in CSS is permanent and don't recalculates if the parent change size but i not sure)?, other option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to use the [graphicProperty](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/MenuItem.html#graphicProperty--) of `MenuItem` to put a `Label` with the needed text as graphic on the first level `Menu`s and `MenuItem`s. Then you can bind the [prefWidthProperty](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/Region.html#prefWidthProperty) of the `Label` to the [widthProperty](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/Region.html#widthProperty--) of the `SplitMenuButton`.

**Example**

```
public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
            Scene scene = new Scene(root,400,400);
            scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());


            SplitMenuButton splitMenuButton = new SplitMenuButton();
            splitMenuButton.setPrefWidth(400);

            MenuItem menuItem = new MenuItem();
            prepareMenuItem(menuItem, "I am a MenuItem", splitMenuButton);
            Menu menu = new Menu();
            prepareMenuItem(menu, "I am a Menu", splitMenuButton);
            MenuItem subMenuItem = new MenuItem("I am not resized!");
            menu.getItems().add(subMenuItem);

            splitMenuButton.getItems().addAll(menu, menuItem);

            root.setCenter(splitMenuButton);

            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void prepareMenuItem(MenuItem menuItem, String text, MenuButton menuButton){
        Label label = new Label();
        label.prefWidthProperty().bind(menuButton.widthProperty());
        label.setText(text);
        label.setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.RIGHT);
        menuItem.setGraphic(label);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

However, the result will be not perfect, as the `MenuItem`s in the dropdown will be slightly wider (because of the internal paddings), but you can tailor the CSS style class `menu-item` a bit to make it absolutely the same size: You can check [modena.css](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8/master/rt/file/f89b7dc932af/modules/controls/src/main/resources/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/modena/modena.css) and the [JavafX CSS Reference Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html).

There is also a dirty solution: for the following picture I have modified `label.prefWidthProperty().bind(menuButton.widthProperty());` to `label.prefWidthProperty().bind(menuButton.widthProperty().subtract(32));`.

[image]